# Issue running "apt-get update": ... does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, kali-linux

```
# apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                           
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                        
Ign:3 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt kali-rolling-pgdg InRelease                                                                        
Hit:5 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease            
Err:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt kali-rolling-pgdg Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 147.75.85.69 80]
Get:4 http://mirror.serverius.net/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.6 kB]
Reading package lists... Done      
E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt kali-rolling-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove PostgreSQL repository from your sources.list beacause it doesn't accept `kali-rolling` distribution, see [this directory](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/).
`postgresql` is packaged in Kali Linux repositories, you can install it through:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install postgresql
```